# Can the thresholds for the autogenerated "3 rude/NC comments in past 7 days" flag be adjusted?

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags

Right now, if a user has 3 or more comments deleted as rude or not constructive, another moderator flag is automatically generated. I think it's useful to know if a user is frequently leaving rude comments, but the threshold for not constructive is too low. I don't generally care that a person has left 3 not constructive comments in a week, or even 2 not constructive and one rude comment.

First, rude and not constructive comments should be treated differently. Right now, there are five reasons to flag a comment - "rude or offensive", "not constructive", "obsolete", "too chatty", and "other" (with a comment). I'd even argue that there's (almost) no difference between "not constructive" and "too chatty", at least that I can see. There's a huge difference between rude or offensive comments or comments that don't add value ("not constructive" or "too chatty"). So the first step is to **generate auto-flags based on more appropriate groupings of comment flags**.

Second, please **adjust the thresholds**. I honestly don't care that much if someone is leaving 3 or even 5 low value comments in a week. Although this could depend on site volume, I suppose. I don't know if this is site-configurable or not, but on Software Engineering, let me see if someone has 7+ low value comments deleted in a week. Why 7? It works out to an average of 1 low value comment per day. On the other hand, 3 rude/offensive comments in a week is better, but I'd even be OK with someone getting 3-5 rude/offensive comments deleted in a 30 day window. Lower the bar for informing me that a user is pushing the bounds of the Be Nice policies.

Comment: Just to note on SO we're declining the autoflags where it's not useful so the team can build up some stats and do whatever in regards to tuning.

Comment: @JonClements Does declining autogenerated flags actually do anything? I wasn't aware it did. If it does, that should be more widely communicated to moderators. I may have missed something that wasn't a mod notice or email.

Comment: Not really. I've always just approved them to dismiss them whether they were useful or not. I think in a chat with the CM team for this autoflag we ended up going for declining them if they're noise or approving them if reasonable. That way they can filter them out and look at ways to improve it (or at least have some form of classification to start with)

Comment: @JonClements Interesting. However, I don't know if stats on SO would be useful to smaller sites. Overall, I like the concept of this auto generated flag - I want to be alerted to users who regularly leave comments that the community perceives to be noise or rude. However, the thresholds are likely to be very different on different sites. Unless moderators across the network are looking at this and the stats are being looked at across the network, too, I don't know how useful declining will be.

Comment: Yeah... I suppose it's going to be site specific but was just pointing out the team is open for adjusting stuff as in principle it's a good idea and in the case of SO we have a sort of system that goes some way towards providing info back so they can tune and see what happens - mostly it's more noise than signal.