# Do 10k users / ♦ moderators get notified if a comment is flagged and handled automatically?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags

The person who posted a comment [does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105340) get notified if their comment is flagged. The ♦ moderators have a flag queue where they can see comments that have been flagged and have not been deleted yet. Occasionally, a comment [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121226) get deleted with a single flag. In this event, are moderators notified or do they see these comments in the flag queue? Are they in any way aware of the fact that a comment got deleted automatically?

I ask because if this is purely automatic then the system might, hypothetically, make mistakes sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, ♦ moderators don't see these comments, just like they don't see posts which are flagged as spam by 6 users. (There's a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303374/295232) to have that changed; I posted a few workarounds as an answer there. Those don't work for comments, though.)

What *could* happen is that multiple 'harassment' and 'unfriendly' comment flags lead to an automatic flag ['multiple rude/abusive comment flags'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286628/295232), but this will not happen if the comments are flagged as 'no longer needed'.

In any case, 10k users don't see comment flags at all.

> I ask because if this is purely automatic then the system might, hypothetically, make mistakes sometimes.

That's a valid concern, but it's a trade-off between a large increase the ♦ moderator workload and the possibility of unjustly removed comments, which are second-class citizens anyway (all important information should be in the post, not in the comments). Stack Exchange has opted for the latter.

Comment: Worth to mention there's no "punishment" at all to the user who posted a comment that got deleted with a single flag automatically, without a mod ever seeing it. Even 100 such comments of same user can be deleted this way, with 0 impact on the user themselves.